# I can receive but not send any iOS Invitation (Shared Albums / Reminders / Calendar events etc)

Tags: ios, icloud

I have tried everything I have found online and all the settings are in place. My wife can invite me to calendar events, reminders, shared albums etc. I, however, with the same settings I can not do it from any of my two iPhones or my Macbook.

I would guess it is a problem with my iOS account itself, but I do not know where the problem is.

Could it be it that I do not have an @iCloud account? My Apple ID is my gmail account.

Best regards

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. Have added your gmail account to your iOS device, other than as an Apple ID? For instance, to receive mail?.

Comment: No, I only have the Apple ID account. No email application or anything related to google installed.

Comment: Does your email or calendar appear on your iPhone?

Comment: did you resolve your problem? I have the same issue with iPhone 6s plus

Answer (score 3):

You need at least *one* account added on your device to be able to invite. You can add it on Settings > Accounts > Add Account.

If you have a provider specific app you may be able to use it to invite other users to calendar events without the previous step.

Shared albums should not need an account though, just the email or phone address associated to the Apple ID of your invitee, depending on the way you chose to send the invitation.

Comment: Thats the problem, Shared albums should be independent, as Notes or reminders. And none of those are working. I've tried to invite people to a shared album using their iMessage phone number, their gmail account and their @iCloud account, non of them work.

Comment: @ElBaulP what is the exact step where it fails?

Comment: I do not see any error or anything, just the invitation never arrives to the recipient.But the other way around it works. Other people can invite me to shared albums.

Comment: How do their invitations arrive?

Comment: As usual, I get a notification

Comment: When you said you don't have an @iCloud account, you meant you haven't setup iCloud on your devices or that you don't have an icloud.com, me.com or mac.com email account?

Comment: I do not have an email account ending on @iCloud. My Apple ID is my google email address.

Comment: Seems it like a strange bug. I'm in contact with apple and they have escalated it to the engineer Phone team. I'll keep you posted.